# freetts - text to speech setting mbrola voice com.sun.speech.freetts.ProcessException: Processing Utterance:

Tags: java, text-to-speech, freetts, google-text-to-speech

Working with ubuntu linux version

Almost done with freetts setting with mbrola voices us1, us2 and us3, but finally getting exceptions.

When i run the below command, i could hear kevin's voice of sun microsystems.

```
    $ java -Dmbrola.base="/home/amphisoft4/Downloads/mbrola" -jar bin/FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar 

    All voices available:
    alan (time domain)
    kevin (general domain)
    kevin16 (general domain)
    mbrola_us1 (general domain)
    mbrola_us2 (general domain)
    mbrola_us3 (general domain
```

But if i specify mbrola_us1

```
    $ java -Dmbrola.base="/home/amphisoft4/Downloads/mbrola" -jar bin/FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar mbrola_us1
```

Im getting

```
All voices available:
    alan (time domain)
    kevin (general domain)
    kevin16 (general domain)
    mbrola_us1 (general domain)
    mbrola_us2 (general domain)
    mbrola_us3 (general domain)

    Using voice: mbrola_us1

    **Processing Utterance: com.sun.speech.freetts.ProcessException: Cannot start mbrola program: [Ljava.lang.String;@62ce0a
    Processing Utterance: com.sun.speech.freetts.ProcessException: Cannot start mbrola program: [Ljava.lang.String;@62ce0a**
```

Comment: thanks for deleting it

Answer (score 0):

Does /home/amphisoft4/Downloads/mbrola/mbrola exist?
If you enter:

```
/home/amphisoft4/Downloads/mbrola/mbrola -h
```

does it work?
Documentation has a note about creating this name from the distro binary. Did you build the binary  and if not it may not be a binary compatable with your Ubuntu release.

hope that give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Finlay what worked for me

I am using ubuntu
Created a folder called mbrola

1. put downloaded mbrola-base for my operating system linux to it
2. put downloaded us1, us2, us3 extracted folders to this folder
3. Install the mbrola in ubuntu by command line.
   sudo apt-get istall mbrola

   After installation use this commad to check where your files has located
   dpkg -L mbrola
4. Copied /usr/bin/mbrola  file to the above mbrola  folder
5. Update the program with the path to above program
   System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "/home/ngs/INCUBATOR/egg-8/libries/MBROLA/mbrola");